# PCL: Plane segmentation

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

When trying to follow the example for cylinder segmentation from [here](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cylinder_segmentation.php#cylinder-segmentation):

I have copied the code but it wont compile on the line:

```
extract.setIndices (inliers_plane);
```

The error I get is:

```
function pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ>::applyFilter(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&): error: undefined reference to 'pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ>::applyFilterIndices(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)'
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

These are the libraries I am linking:

```
-lpcl_io 
-lpcl_visualization 
-lpcl_tracking 
-lpcl_common 
-lpcl_surface 
-lpcl_kdtree 
-lpcl_keypoints 
-lpcl_octree 
-lpcl_registration 
-lpcl_sample_consensus 
-lpcl_search 
-lpcl_segmentation 
-lpcl_geometry 
-lpcl_surface 
-lpcl_features
```

Comment: Thats a linker error, not a compile error.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks, I found the library I was not linking against

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to link against `pcl_filters` too